# V2.1 API body HTML has unclosed li tags

Tags: support, bug, api-v2.1

The Stack Exchange API (with a safe filter) is returning question body content with malformed HTML, specifically `<li>` elements that do not have closing tags (and no valid parent).

I've seen this occur with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774073/strange-behavior-of-length-command-oracle), and the server response on the actual Stack Overflow page also includes the same issues.

The problem I'm facing is that I'd like to embed the question body in a custom web page and the unclosed elements are causing the browser to misinterpret the HTML (particularly when body content is put into container `<li>` elements).

So my question is: is this a bug in the Stack Exchange API (or backend), or should API clients not assume that body content will be well-formed HTML? If the answer is the latter, what kinds of workarounds are available for displaying body content on the web in a more predictable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The code in question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19774073/331508) was not generated by Stack Exchange. [It was generated by a user.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19774073/revisions)

So, yes, quite often, the HTML (and all other code samples generated by users) will be malformed.

However, in this case, note that [`<li>` tags are not required to have closing tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-tags).  I agree that it is bad form to leave them off, though.